# How to assign numeric value to new word within column in R

Tags: r, text, mapping, numeric, assign

I'm assigning values to a list of fruits like this in R.

```
#input csv of fruits

fruits
 apple
 pineapple
 orange
 pear

fruits <- data.frame(fruits = c("apple", "pineapple", "orange", "pear"))

mapping <- c("apple" = 1, "orange"= 10, "pear" = 5,"pineapple" = 11)

fruits$value <- mapping[fruits[,1]]

#output

fruits     value
 apple     1
 pineapple 11
 orange    10
 pear      5
```

When the fruit list gets updated, say by adding mango and kiwi, I want any possible unexpected word/text of fruit to be assigned the numeric value of 1 without having to add that specific word to the mapping.

Running the code with new fruits outputs this.

```
fruits     value
 apple     1
 pineapple NA
 orange    11
 pear      NA
 mango     5
 kiwi      10

fruits2 = data.frame(fruits = 
  c("apple", "pineapple", "orange", "pear", "mango", "kiwi"))
```

I would expect the NA to be with mango and kiwi but they are not.

How to do I assign the value 1 to new fruits not included in the original mapping?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From you mapping vector create the mapping dataframe , then using `merge`

```
mapdf = data.frame(fruits = names(mapping), value = mapping, row.names = NULL)

yourdf = merge(df,mapdf,by = 'fruits',all.x = T)
yourdf
     fruits value
1     apple     1
2      kiwi    NA
3     mango    NA
4    orange    10
5      pear     5
6 pineapple    11
```

---

About fill the `NA` to `1`

```
yourdf$value[is.na(yourdf$value)] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all if `fruits` is a factor convert it into character

```
df$fruits <- as.character(df$fruits)
```

Then you do

```
df$value <- mapping[df$fruits]

df
#     fruits value
#1     apple     1
#2 pineapple    11
#3    orange    10
#4      pear     5
#5     mango    NA
#6      kiwi    NA
```

This will give `NA`s for the `fruits` which are not in `mapping`. Now turn the `NA`s into 1's.

```
df$value[is.na(df$value)] <- 1

df
#     fruits value
#1     apple     1
#2 pineapple    11
#3    orange    10
#4      pear     5
#5     mango     1
#6      kiwi     1
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to do I assign the value 1 to new fruits not included in the original mapping?

If you're just looking up one column, `match` is an option:

```
mymapping = c(mapping, default = 1)
m = match(fruits2$fruits, names(mymapping), nomatch=length(mymapping))

fruits2$value = mymapping[m]

     fruits value
1     apple     1
2 pineapple    11
3    orange    10
4      pear     5
5     mango     1
6      kiwi     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse solution :

```
library(tidyverse)
fruits2 %>%
  left_join(enframe(mapping),by=c(fruits="name")) %>%
  replace_na(replace = list(value=1))
#      fruits value
# 1     apple     1
# 2 pineapple    11
# 3    orange    10
# 4      pear     5
# 5     mango     1
# 6      kiwi     1
# Warning message:
# Column `fruits`/`name` joining factor and character vector, coercing into character vector
```